# Flash Cards with incrementations of Q #1, Q #2,

Tags: ms-word

I have downloaded a template for Flash Cards and would like to expand on it so there is a header on each of them that starts with Question #1, Question #2, etc.

How do I make the number automatically increment the header instead of changing it manually?

It should look something like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Kasper,

Its not as exciting as Microsoft word, but perhaps [this is a functional alternative for your flash cards?](http://dogfeatherdesign.com/electronic-3x5-cards/)  It does include the "card number" but also includes a random button if that helps folks learn better.  You appear to have pretty good software skills, and there is nothing beyond HTML, JavaScript and CSS.